# Filter required data from json array

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to filter data using below shown method to filter data from json array..

This is what should happen, 
When `sizeSelectedItem = Sausage Crust Large` then `resultTopping` should be two `Add BBQ Chicken-120.00` and one `Add Cheese-120.00`, which are related to Sausage Crust Large.

When `sizeSelectedItem = Pan Large` then `resultTopping` should be one `Add BBQ Chicken-120.00`, which are related to Pan Large.

`List<String> topDescription` is all 5 `Add BBQ Chicken-120.00`,

**UPDATED CODE**

```
   try {
                if ((object.getString("ItemCode")).equals(itemCode)) {

                    JSONArray subMenuArray = object
                            .getJSONArray("SubMenuEntity");

                    for (int j = 0; j < subMenuArray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject subMenuObject = subMenuArray
                                .getJSONObject(j);

                        if ((subMenuObject.getString("Description"))
                                .equals(sizeSelectedItem)) {

                            JSONArray extraItemEntityArray = subMenuObject
                                    .getJSONArray("ExtraItemEntity");

                            for (int k = 0; k < extraItemEntityArray.length(); k++) {
                                JSONObject objectE = extraItemEntityArray
                                        .getJSONObject(k);

                                if ((objectE.getString("Description")) != null
                                        && (objectE.getString("Type"))
                                                .equals("E")) {

                                    topDescription.add(objectE
                                            .getString("Description"));

                                    topPrice.add(objectE.getString("Price"));
                                    Log.i("ExtraDescriptionPrice",
                                            objectE.getString("Price"));

                                    Log.i("ExtraMainMenuCode", objectE
                                            .getString("ExtraMainMenuCode"));
                                    topMainMenuCode.add(objectE
                                            .getString("ExtraMainMenuCode"));

                                    Log.i("ExtraSubMenuCode", objectE
                                            .getString("ExtraSubMenuCode"));
                                    topSubMenuCode.add(objectE
                                            .getString("ExtraSubMenuCode"));

                                    Log.i("Type", objectE.getString("Type"));
                                    topType.add(objectE.getString("Type"));
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But this returns null, can anyone help me to work this out.

json response

```
    {  
          "ItemCode":"BPM ",
          "SubMenuEntity":[  
             {  
            "Description":"Sausage Crust Large",
            "ExtraItemEntity":[  
               {  
                  "Description":"Add BBQ Chicken-120.00",
               },
               {  
                  "Description":"Add BBQ Chicken-120.00",
               },
               {  
                  "Description":"Add Cheese-120.00",
               }
            ],
            "Crust":"Sausage"
         },
         {  
            "Description":"Pan Large",
            "ExtraItemEntity":[  
               {  
                  "Description":"Add BBQ Chicken-120.00",
               }
            ],
            "Crust":"Pan"
         },
         {  
            "Description":"Pan Mediam",
            "ExtraItemEntity":[  
               {  
                  "Description":"Add BBQ Chicken-120.00",
               },
               {  
                  "Description":"Add BBQ Chicken-120.00",
               }
            ],
            "Crust":"Pan"
         },
         {  
            "Description":"Personal Pan",
            "ExtraItemEntity":[  

            ],
            "Crust":"Pan"
         }
      ],
      "Category":"1PI",
   }
```

Comment: When `sizeSelectedItem = Pan Large` how can `resultTopping` be one `Add BBQ Chicken-120.00` while you're checking this `if (!topDescription.get(i).contains(sizeSelectedItem))` in your snippet ?

Comment: I was trying out this code, I need help to figure that out how to do.. is it possible to do using this method if not please suggest me some new idea.

Comment: please check my answer and remember to handle the `org.json.JSONException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your json response if you want to get the toppings related to the `Description` attribute you should try doing like this:

```
public ArrayList<String> getFilteredToppings(String sizeSelectedItem) {
    ArrayList<String> resultTopping = new ArrayList<String>();
    sizeSelectedItem = sizeSP.getSelectedItem().toString();
    JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject("json response");
    JSONArray SubMenuEntity= jobj.getJSONArray("SubMenuEntity");
    for(int k=0;k< SubMenuEntity.length();k++){
        JSONObject object=SubMenuEntity.getJSONObject(k);
        if(object.getString("Description").equals(sizeSelectedItem)){
            for(int j=0;j<object.getJSONArray("ExtraItemEntity").length();j++)
                resultTopping.add(object.getJSONArray("ExtraItemEntity").getJSONObject(j).getString("Description"));
            break;
        }
    }
    return resultTopping;
}
```

Comment: Give me some time, ill try out this,

Comment: I have updated my code, can u check it please.. results keep adding to the existing results. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Which results keep adding to the existing results ? You should have just one output since the loop brakes at the first matching description.. You should update the `json` too and change your question so that I can understand what you want to achieve a the end..

Comment: I just had to initialize it after loop starts, now its working perfectly